Make a ticking javascript clock inside an ajax request that does not flicker
I am trying to make a ticking clock that updates every second (or every new minute is acceptable).
My problem arises because I am using ajax request.
A new ajax request is sent every time I choose a different timezone from a scroll down menu.
Ajax request is executing below code.
If I reload the page with for example $timezone = 'Asia/Tokyo', then everything is fine. The problem arises when I do an ajax request through a drop down menu with a different timezone, like $timezone = 'Europe/Berlin'.
The result will be an output on the website that is flickering between the two different times.
So: when I select a different timezone, like timezone for Europe/Berlin from the drop down menu, an ajax request is sent and code below is executed, and setInterval(showTime, 1000); updates the time every second, meaning, the website will show new output every second when the JavaScript function will execute. But between the JavaScript updates the time on the website will fall back to the time and timezone before the ajax request, showing time for $timezone = 'Asia/Tokyo'! So the displayed time will be a flickering time alternating: Europe/Berlin>Asia/Tokyo>Europe/Berlin>Asia/Tokyo...changing every second.
(Also, in the output I also get a "GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)"-ending. But that is not important, I want to discard it from my output).
Flickering clock between timezones every second because of setInterval(showTime, 1000); https://imgur.com/a/yX0yMj0
You will most probably NOT be able to recreate the error, since my $timezone comes from an ajax request (drop down menu) and not by setting it like $timezone = 'Asia/Tokyo'.
<?php
$timezone = 'Asia/Tokyo';
//  $timezone = 'America/New_York';
//  $timezone = 'Europe/Berlin';
//  $timezone = 'Asia/Singapore';
        
$datetime = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone($timezone));
$formattedDate = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        
echo '$timezone = ' . $timezone;
echo '<br>';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($datetime);
echo '</pre>';
echo '$formattedDate Shows Static Time in ' . $timezone . ' = ' .  $formattedDate;
echo '<br><br>';
        
echo '
<script>
(function() {
    var serverTime = new Date("' . $formattedDate . '");
    var serverOffset = serverTime.getTime() - new Date().getTime();
        
    function showTime() {
        var now = new Date();
        var correctTime = new Date(now.getTime() + serverOffset);
        
        var formattedTime = correctTime.getFullYear() + "-" +
                            String(correctTime.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0") + "-" +
                            String(correctTime.getDate()).padStart(2, "0") + " " +
                            String(correctTime.getHours()).padStart(2, "0") + ":" +
                            String(correctTime.getMinutes()).padStart(2, "0") + ":" +
                            String(correctTime.getSeconds()).padStart(2, "0");
        
        
        document.getElementById("current-time9").textContent = correctTime;
    }
        
    setInterval(showTime, 1000); // Update every second
})();
</script>
      
<span>current-time9  </span><span id="current-time9"></span><br><br>
';
?>


Maybe you have more than one setinterval running.  Try logging servertime inside showtime - possibly you will see alternating values of servertime indicating more than one interval.

AJAX is by default Asynchronous

Yes, this could be the case about more than one setinterval running . What can I do about it?

Also make it easier to test by having all HTML and JavaScript outside an echo: ?><script> …..</script><?….

If I were you I will disable the dropdown when ajax is triggered, and then enable it back after ajax is successful

Is it possible to solve this with a second, additional, javascript function?

ChatGPT output is banned here. It's notoriously unreliable. You've come here asking for our advice. The ChatGPT output is irrelevant,.

Wenn ever possible draw in a https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame

This code snippet is incomplete. There's no AJAX call here so it's impossible to see how that interacts with your other JavaScript. I think possibly you're using a form with a submit that is forcing a reload of the page. There's no point in posting code that doesn't show the problem. See [mcve]

Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

ChatGPT can give ideas of what could be reconsidered. Right now, I think that JavaScript is fetching and updating the time every second, but JavaScript has no memory, so old time comes back after every update. Can I create a JavaScript with memory, that stores the timezone somehow?

It's probably because the old setInterval is running, you can use clearInterval(interval, to remove the old interval after changing timezones.
const myInterval = setInterval(showTime, 1000);
clearInterval(myInterval);


Do you know where I could put it?

@user23427046 how should we know, when you haven't shown us how you are using AJAX to update this?
